# is freelancing halal?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, zakat

I want to be a freelancer. I want to make a web site, but I know that it is almost impossible to earn 100 percent halal in the world of internet. Because when you go to make a web site, it is seen that the client can sometimes say that he will put pictures of girls here, which then there is no way but to be forced. Then, as far as I know, money is mixed with haram. If I want to live in a 100 percent halal way, is it better to leave this path? Or will the money be purified through zakat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freelancing can be done for any field. You can leave such client. Not all client will ask you to do the same. You can find clients who are in business dont support nudity, gambling etc. I am myself an accountant and doing freelancing so all my work is 100% halaal because i am providing accountancy services as a freelancer. Almost all types of businesses needs freelancer for marketing, web development, bookkeeping, content writing etc so you need to find those which dont violate shariah rules. It has nothing to do with freelancing its all about choice and selection